# Find mysql replications diffs patterns

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication, diff, percona

I'm using pt-table-checksum and pt-table-sync to check for differences in my replicas. 
when I use pt-table-sync with the -print option, I can only see the master values.

How can I show the conflicting slave values as well? I want to see if I can find a pattern of which those diffs occur by.

Answer (score 1):

Using [**pt-table-sync**](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.0/pt-table-sync.html) with these options

- `--print`
- `--sync-to-master`

will report the SQL changes to **execute on the Slave** to make the Slave match the Master.

The Master is simply connected for comparison purposes.

The Percona Documenation on --print option says

> Print queries that will resolve differences.
>
> If you don’t trust pt-table-sync, or just want to see what it will do, this is a good way to be safe. These queries are valid SQL and you can run them yourself if you want to sync the tables manually.

For emphasis : Do not execute the output of `--print` AND `--sync-to-master` on a Master. Execute it on a Slave only.

If you are using Circular Replication, do this

```
echo "SET SQL_LOG_BIN = 0;" > ChangesToSlave.sql
pt-table-sync --print --sync-to-master ... >> ChangesToSlave.sql
```

then you can run `ChangesToSlave.sql` on a Slave.

Comment: Good answer, but it does not provide a real answer to the question: *What are the conflicting values of the row on the slave side?* What I did was looking in the checkums table `pt-table-checksum` created using a very small chunk size - this pointed me to a bunch of rows easy to spot the difference myself. It turned out to be a different timezone producing different `NOW()` values.